# Свайп UITableViewCell влево/вправо

Tags: swipe, ios7, uitableview

Как сделать свайп влево/вправо ячейки в `UItableViewController`? На подобие той анимации удаления при сдвиге влево, только я хочу сделать, чтобы в место удаления была другая кнопка.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите этот компонент:[SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)  , похоже то что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

реализовав методы UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       return NSLocalizedString(@"My custom title", @"")
}
```

и UITableViewDataSource:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return YES
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      /* My custom code here */
}
```

можно добиться желаемого результата без особых усилий